# Different Screen size on Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this layout problem with the `ImageView`. I already created the layout-small, layout-large, but none of this fixes it. Because the screen of Nexus 5 and Nexus One are in the same category (layout-normal).

You can see on the screenshot of the Nexus One (480x800) that the buttons don't appear, because of the height of the `ImageView`.

[image: Nexus one]

I want the layout to looks like on the Nexus 5.

[image: nexus 5]

Is there any way to solve this?

This my layout code:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/my_imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:onClick="onPlaySound" />
```

Comment: I don't get the picture...

Comment: And it's not showing? Please instead of adding code in the comments, add it to the question (edit the question)

Comment: link of the photo http://i.stack.imgur.com/EVSqu.png

Comment: You should post your layout file and be clear about what you want at achieve.

Comment: @tynn I want a way to make the layout appear equals on the two screen (480x800) and (1080x1920)

Comment: You should post the whole layout file, not only the one view, eventhough it shows the problem. With all data needed, you'll find help for that. Like Matthew pointed out, an implementation of `RelativeLayout` would be the right thing to do here.

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't posted all of your code, I'm going to make an educated guess at what is happening here.

The image view that you have posted has a fixed height of 350dp with a margin top of 19dp. 369dp is roughly 553px on the nexus one (hdpi screen). This leaves about 247px for the rest of your content. Which includes you action bar, text labels and buttons including any margins and padding. I'm assuming that the total px space taken up by your action bar and labels is too much for your buttons to show on the nexus one.

If you are using a relative layout you want to tell you image view to match parent and then use layout rules to tell the image view to sit above the labels and below the action bar. This will allows the buttons, labels and action bar to remain fixed and allow the image to fill the remaining space.

Comment: Thank you.. I already fix... i just add `android:layout_weight="1"` on the image view

Comment: LinearLayout then :D

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate layout for different screen sizes here is a example [link](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html) In this way u can change and modify your layout according to the screen size

Comment: Thank you.. I already fix... i just add `android:layout_weight="1"` on the image view